# What are the standard URL suffix views that every SharePoint professional should know?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, url, tools

There are certain lesser-known URL suffixes that can be quite useful in SharePoint, such as

> {PageUrl}?contents=1

for web part maintenance and

> {PageUrl}_layouts/UsageDetails.aspx

for displaying usage statistics.

Does anybody have anymore of these, or is there a listing already available?
Specifically I am interested in pages that are not easily accessible from the GUI (such as site settings).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I will convert this to a community wiki due to its open-ended-ness

Answer (score 6):

Here's one that's useful when you want to put a Web Part page into edit mode but you don't have the option in the UI:

```
?toolpaneview=2
```

I explain it more fully in this post:
http://sympmarc.com/2010/10/27/add-web-parts-to-sharepoint-forms-without-sharepoint-designer/

Answer (score 6):

`[url]?IsDlg=1` renders the page in dialog mode (no navigation).

`[url]?mobile=0` renders the desktop page on a mobile device.

`[ListViewURL]?FilterField1=fieldName&FilterValue1=value` filters a list view (can be extended to FilterFieldnn).

Answer (score 3):

Let's start with

```
{PageUrl}/_layouts/settings.aspx (for site settings)
{PageUrl}/_layouts/viewlsts.aspx (for Site content)
{PageUrl}/_layouts/sitemanager.aspx (for content and structure)
{PageUrl}/_Layouts/ChangeSiteMasterPage.aspx (switch master page)
```

Comment: Fair enough, but I was enquiring about the less obvious ones which can not be easily accessed via the GUI (such as site settings etc).

Comment: To be fair, Usage Details in your post is also accessible (at least a very similar one through "Site Web Analytics reports" and "Site Collection Web Analytics reports" in Site settings ;) And master page link is not there in Site settings without publishing enabled on the site (works for 2010)

Answer (score 2):

1. User information List `_catalogs/users/simple.aspx`
2. Taxonomy Hidden List `Lists/TaxonomyHiddenList/AllItems.aspx`
3. owssvr.dll suffixes like:

> The following example creates a new Custom list named "Employees" on a
>   site called STSWeb1:
>   `http://STSWeb1/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?Cmd=NewList&ListTemplate=100&Title=Employees&LangID=1033`
>
> This example displays the Discussions list as a CAML file:
>   `http://STSWeb1/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?Cmd=Display&List=Discussions&XMLDATA=TRUE`
>
> The next example exports the Discussions list to a Microsoft Excel
>   worksheet. Note that the unique GUID for the associated view must be
>   assigned to the View parameter.

```
http://STSWeb1/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=109&Using=_layouts/query.iqy&List=Discussions&View={4442B73A-8E2B-4edc-A272-94E3615008C5}&CacheControl=1
```

Refer [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd588673(v=office.11).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd588673%28v=office.11%29.aspx) for OWSSVR.dll suffixes

Answer (score 1):

`http://{hostname}/{catalog site}/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx` -  Grant permission to an app page. Refer an article [Create a workflow with elevated permissions by using the SharePoint 2013 Workflow platform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822159%28v=office.15%29.aspx) for a details.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite:

```
/_layouts/15/closeConnection.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true
```

And sometimes useful:

```
/_layouts/savetmpl.aspx
```

This is used to open the "Save site as template" form, which is unavailable, if the publishing feature is enabled. For more information look [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/richin/archive/2011/12/05/save-site-as-template-option-missing-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx).